# I want to call Python in Node.js and use SymPy module

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express, sympy

I use Node.js and Express as server side language.
And I made a website using AWS.

I need to use Python because I need complicated calculations.
However, I don't know how to call Python from Node.js.

Please tell me how to use Python's SymPy module in Node.js.

Comment: You can use [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you need to call a external script from your Node.js application, you can always [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) a process to do so.

There is (obviously) a npm module to make it easier for you to use a python script from Node.js. You can use [python-shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) module to launch your "complicated calculation" scrip if you're not able to find the equivalent in Node.js ecosystem.

Here a basic example inspired by the [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) & python-shell documentation:

*script.py*

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
print (limit(sin(x)/x, x, 0))
```

*app.js*

```
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

PythonShell.run('script.py', null, function (err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(res[0]);  // 1
});
```

Also pay attention to have the SymPy module in your path.